# How to add a dynamic prefix to Nuxt 3 page-based routing?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm working on a multi-tenant app in Nuxt 3 where most routes are prefixed by a reference to their organization. For example:

```
/abc-org/questions
/abc-org/settings
/foo-co/questions
/foo-co/settings
...
```

What is the best way to achieve this with Nuxt3's [page-based routing](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing)?

It seems like [baseURL](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#baseurl) is more for the case where you want the whole site to be served with a single prefix. Is there a way to achieve this without dropping to the raw Vue router?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve that (please have a look to the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing))

The simplest is to have, for your example, this file structure:

```
/pages/[organization]/questions.vue
/pages/[organization]/settings.vue
```

this way you would inside any of those .vue access to the organization:

```
const organization = route.params.organization // 'abc-org' or 'foo-co'
```

Or you can have an approach like this, in your `app/router.options.ts`:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig> {
  // https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html#routes
  routes: (_routes) => [
    {
       name: `questions`,
       path: '/:organzation/questions',
       file: resolve(__dirname, '../pages/questions.vue'),
    },
    {
       name: `settings`,
       path: '/:organzation/settings',
       file: resolve(__dirname, '../pages/settings.vue'),
    },
  ],
}
```

And again: `const organization = route.params.organization // 'abc-org' or 'foo-co'`

Or even:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig> {
  // https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html#routes
  routes: (_routes) => [
    {
       name: `organization`,
       path: '/:organzation/:section',
       file: resolve(__dirname, '../pages/organization.vue'),
    },
  ],
}
```

And in organization.vue:

```
const organization = route.params.organization // 'abc-org' or 'foo-co'
const section = route.params.section // 'settings' or 'questions'
```

Don't forget to declare `route`

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route = useRoute();
```